# Can this display's address be changed?

Tags: display, adafruit

I need two displays hooked up to an Arduino MKR Wifi 1010, and I saw this video which shows how to do it: [this video](https://youtu.be/yef23sJjiU0). I also would like to have a full color oled display about 1 inch big so I would like to use [this display](https://www.adafruit.com/product/684). But I don't believe that you can change the address and would not like to buy it until I find out if you can.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Adafruit display uses SPI. Different SPI devices can be selected via their respective CS (Chip Select) pins. You can connect the SPI bus (MOSI, MISO ans SCK) to multiple displays in parallel and choose which one to control by enabling their CS pin (although the display library will usually do this for you).

Answer (score 3):

There are two different OLED screens in the links you shared.

###### 1. OLED Display on Adafruit Link

The OLED display on the Adafruit link does not have an address as it communicates via the SPI interface.

###### 2. OLED Display on YouTube Link

This OLED display communicates via I2C interface. OLED displays that communicate over the I2C interface have a slave address. This provides the possibility to connect devices with different slave addresses on the same I2C line. The address of this screen can only take two different values. If you solder the 0 Ω resistor to the left field, its address will be `0x7A`; if you solder the 0 Ω resistor to the right field, its address will be `0x78`.

---

###### Suggestions

[This OLED display](https://www.adafruit.com/product/326) with 0.96" screen size communicates via I2C interface and its address can be changed. If a 0 Ω resistor is connected to the **A0** pad, the I2C slave address of the OLED display will be `0x3D`; otherwise the I2C slave address of the OLED display will be `0x3C`.

[image]

Comment: If you have a address conflict the generic solution would be to use I2C mux that will switch between the circuits or use different hardware I2C or bitbang a software I2C.